# php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force No Metadata Classes to process

Tags: mongodb, symfony

When I type:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

The result is:

> "No Metadata Classes to process"

I have clear the cache but the same problem.

Comment: There are no valid entities then in the bundle\entity namespace

Comment: but i have for exemple the Products Document

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to use ODM commands not ORM commands.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Regenerate the schema from console then all commands like

php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

will work. try this solution